# How to get an Instance of Apex class in VF

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have just came across something that I am unsure about. The link below gives an example of how to use an apex controller with VF. My question is, when does the constructor get called? There is no *new* keyword so no object is created and therefore the constructor never gets called. Does VF implicitly do this?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes the page constructs the controller and any extensions. See for example [Order of Execution for Visualforce Page Get Requests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_get_request.htm):

[image: A diagram of how a Visualforce page interacts with a controller extention or a custom controller class during a get request]